# Regex for numbers?

Tags: regex

So i made this regex to find personal ID in denmark:

```
[0-3][0-9][0-1][1-9]\d{2}[-\s]\d{4}?[^0-9]*|[0-3][0-9][0-1][1-9]\d{2}\d{4}
```

So it will detect number in the order:

```
1405901190
140590 1190
140590-1190
```

But how do i make 1 regex code that detects the 6 first numbers in each of the 3 lines. And a nr2 regex that detects the 4 last numbers in all 3 lines?

So looking for 2 codes.

Thanks

Comment: No need to have two regexps, just use capturing groups. See [`^([0-3]\d[0-1][1-9]\d{2})[-\s]?(\d{4})$`](https://regex101.com/r/RZxHLw/3)

Comment: But i need 2 lines to cheat my program :) My program only read the first 6 words, so a full line wont work. meaning, if i split it up to 2 lines i can get it to work. :)

Comment: What is the program? What exactly is the purpose of what you are doing? Please update your question with the necessary details. Also, it is important to know what regex library you are using. See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/dOP7ZN/1) and [this one](https://regex101.com/r/dOP7ZN/2).

Comment: So i want 2 regex codes. 1 that gets 6 numbers in a row.
nr2 code should get the 4 last numbers in my 3 line of numbers.

Comment: "I want" is a poor description of the problem. Please provide the [details I asked for in the previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542522/regex-for-numbers?noredirect=1#comment80039825_46542522).

Comment: my program use a lucene database. the program is called "nuix". the problem is in the search string, it will only look at the first 6 words in a string. I can trick the search string if i split it up to 2 line of regex, meaning it first search for the first 6 numbers, and then the last 4 numbers. meaning i tricked it. Have done this with other code.

Comment: @Deathleecher You should not expect good answers from a poor question... If it does not works as expected, you should clearly say what you get and what you expect. Also, answers to comments should be clear. You should put a **lot more effort and time** in your questions and comments.

Comment: @Deathleecher There is something that does not click: Lucene regexes do not support `\d` and lots of stuff. Judging by [this reference](https://www.nuix.com/2014/07/01/textual-analytics-named-entity-extraction) , it is clearly not Lucene.

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -oP '[0-3][0-9][0-1][1-9]\d{2}' /tmp/test2
140590
140590
140590

grep -oP '\d{4}$' /tmp/test2 
1190
1190
1190

cat /tmp/test2
1405901190
140590 1190
140590-1190
```

Comment: So the first code works fine. But "\d{4}$" only work with the 4 numbers in "140590-1190" it dosent take the 4 numbers in the other rows.

Comment: I disagree, it takes from all three rows as I have shown above.

Comment: It would be preferred to write this as others have suggested to use 2 capture groups, but you wanted two separate commands.

Comment: So for some reason the code i said didten work, works fine in my program :S But the code: '[0-3][0-9][0-1][1-9]\d{2}(?=[-\s]{0,1}\d{4})'. Dose not work in my program.

Comment: remove the fancy stuff at the end of the regex, it might not be supported.  I've updated my answer